# How to determine law of a random variable from its cumulative distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and let $X$ be a random variable.

Suppose that we are given the distribution of $X$, denoted by $F_X$. i.e. $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)$.

From $F_X$, how do we get $P(X \in B)$ , where $B$ is Borel?

I know that there is a unique probability measure, say $L_X$, on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ such that $L_X(B) = P(X \in B)$ where $B$ is Borel.
But, how do we know existence?

Comment: $P(X \in B)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1_B(x) F_X(dx)$, which can be understood in the sense of the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral. Alternately, you could say that $B \mapsto P(X \in B)$ is the extension of the measure $P(X \in (a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$ to all of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Other options exist depending on what you want to do with this expression.

Comment: @Ian I am not so familiar with the Lebesuge-Stiletjes integral, so I am just guessing that, are you looking at $F_X$ as a measure on $R$?

Comment: Not exactly. Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral In fact the Riemann-Stieltjes integral will also work in this setting, since $F$ has total variation $1$.

Comment: @Ian I will take a look at the wiki. for your alternative construction, are you extending the measure to $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ using Caratheordory's extension theorem?

Comment: That's one way to do it, yes.